# How to use FontAwesome in Android

Tags: android, icons, font-awesome

I want to use **FontAwesome** in my Android app. I am obtaining the icons from the server. The server sends me the icons with the following format:

```
"icon": "fas fa-laptop"
```

I don't know how can I show these icons. 
I can show icons with Unicode **f3ce** but I don't know how can I show icons with the above format.

Comment: Did you tried this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-use-font-awesome-icons-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [This](https://github.com/amangarg95/AwesomeTextView) library to help you get started using FontAwesome, you start by adding a text view to your layout:

```xml
    <com.amangarg.library.AwesomeTextView
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/someText"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Then you get a reference to that textView and you add your icons:

```kotlin
val tv = findViewById<AwesomeTextView>(R.id.someText)
tv.setFontAwesomeText("fa-solid fa-star")
```

Comment: the library doesnt seem to have a jar right? youd have to import all the library source to your project?